# How to find crc32 of big files?

Tags: php, checksum, crc32

The PHP's crc32  support string as input.And For a file , below code will work OFC.

```
crc32(file_get_contents("myfile.CSV"));
```

But if file goes huge (2 GB) it might raise out of memory Fatal error.

So any way around to find checksum of huge files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This function](http://php.net/manual/function.crc32.php#31832) in the User Contributed Notes to `crc32()` claims to calculate the value without loading the file in full. If it works correctly, it should eliminate any memory problems.

For a file larger than 2 GB, it is however likely to stop at the same 32-bit limitation you are encountering right now.

If possible, I would invoke an external tool that can calculate the checksum for files as large as the one at hand.

Comment: You know any external tool that will calculate crc32 ? I am on Linux( Debian Flavor.)

Comment: @zaf  - Worked awesomely You are a **STAR**

Answer (score 6):

PHP doesn't support files larger than 2GB (32bit limitation)

And more efficient way to calculate crc32 from files:

```
$hash = hash_file('crc32b',"myfile.CSV" );
```

Comment: edited once more - `crc32b` is correct hash algorithm for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

**dev-null-dweller**'s answer is IMO the way to go.

However, for those who are looking for a memory-efficient PHP4 backport of `hash_file('crc32b', $filename);`, here is a solution based on [**this PHP manual comment**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php#99939), with some improvements:

- It now gives exactly the same results than `hash_file()`
- It supports 32 bit & 64 bit architectures.

**Warning:** perfs are ugly. Trying to improve.

Note: I've tried a solution based on the C source code from zaf's comment, but I could not quickly enough succeed to port it to PHP.

```
if (!function_exists('hash_file'))
{
    define('CRC_BUFFER_SIZE', 8192);

    function hash_file($algo, $filename, $rawOutput = false)
    {
        $mask32bit = 0xffffffff;

        if ($algo !== 'crc32b')
        {
            trigger_error("Unsupported hashing algorightm '".$algo."'", E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }

        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');

        if ($fp === false)
        {
            trigger_error("Could not open file '".$filename."' for reading.", E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }

        static $CRC32Table, $Reflect8Table;
        if (!isset($CRC32Table))
        {
            $Polynomial = 0x04c11db7;
            $topBit = 1 << 31;

            for($i = 0; $i < 256; $i++)
            {
                $remainder = $i << 24;
                for ($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++)
                {
                    if ($remainder & $topBit)
                        $remainder = ($remainder << 1) ^ $Polynomial;
                    else
                        $remainder = $remainder << 1;

                    $remainder &= $mask32bit;
                }

                $CRC32Table[$i] = $remainder;

                if (isset($Reflect8Table[$i]))
                    continue;
                $str = str_pad(decbin($i), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $num = bindec(strrev($str));
                $Reflect8Table[$i] = $num;
                $Reflect8Table[$num] = $i;
            }
        }

        $remainder = 0xffffffff;
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $data = fread($fp, CRC_BUFFER_SIZE);
            $len = strlen($data);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
            {
                $byte = $Reflect8Table[ord($data[$i])];
                $index = (($remainder >> 24) & 0xff) ^ $byte;
                $crc = $CRC32Table[$index];
                $remainder = (($remainder << 8) ^ $crc) & $mask32bit;
            }
        }

        $str = decbin($remainder);
        $str = str_pad($str, 32, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $remainder = bindec(strrev($str));
        $result = $remainder ^ 0xffffffff;
        return $rawOutput ? strrev(pack('V', $result)) : dechex($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I guess there should be a way to hash a file block by block using the native crc32() method. I remember from implementing a crc16 function (long ago), that crc16(data.crc16(data)) == 0x0000. If there is a way to guess what data to prepend to the next block in order to obtain last block's crc32, you're good to go. In other words, if you can efficiently calculate a 32-bit value x from crc32(block1) such that crc32(x)=crc32(block1), then crc32(block1.block2)=crc32(x.block2). Anyone has an idea whether this would be feasible?

Comment: Even better, I found [this post](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php#100060) that lets think that you can come up with a function crc32_combine() such that crc32_combine(crc32(block1),crc32(block2)) = crc32(block1.block2). Unfortunately, the original post it's referring to is gone! Open source Zlib has an implementation of crc32_combine() we could peek at, though. I'll try digging this up.